# MVC 5 Custom Html Helper extension issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, html-helper

I'm trying to create a custom html helper class.
I have the below as a very simple start, complies fine:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures;

namespace Mobile.HtmlHelpers
{
    public static class RequestBox
    {
        public static HtmlString CascadeBoxFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, object htmlAttributes = null)
        {
            HtmlString html = (HtmlString)HtmlHelperInputExtensions.TextBoxFor(helper, expression);
            return html;
        }
        // IHtmlContent html = HtmlHelperInputExtensions.TextBoxFor(htmlHelper, expression);
    }
}
```

I am trying to call it and the system doesn't like it..
I can see it if I use:

```cs
@foreach (var item in Model.RequestModel.Requests)
{     
    @RequestBox.CascadeBoxFor(x=>item.EmployeeDescription)
}
```

But I get:

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
>   Error CS7036 There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'expression' of 'RequestBox.CascadeBoxFor<TModel, TValue>(HtmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>>, object)' Mobile..NET Framework 4.6.1

If I try suggestions of it being an extension and I should be able to use `@Html.CascadeBoxFor(x => item.EmployeeDescription)`, I get:

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
>   Error CS1061 'IHtmlHelper<RequestPageModel>' does not contain a definition for 'CascadeBoxFor' and no extension method 'CascadeBoxFor' accepting a first argument of type 'IHtmlHelper<RequestPageModel>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    Mobile..NET Framework 4.6.1

Can anyone tell me what is missing here?

Comment: Is `item.EmployeeDescription` an `Expression`?

Comment: Have you included `@using Mobile.HtmlHelpers` in the view (or added it in your `web.config.cs` file)?